# can somebody explain how this works?

Tags: java, swing, scope, initializing

I have this line of code.

```
class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{  
    public ButtonPanel()
    {  
        yellowButton = new JButton("Yellow");
```

and It works, I thought Java needs to know the type of yellowButton before creating an instance of a jButton like this?

```
JButton yellowButton = new JButton("Yellow");
```

can somebody explain how this works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it really does work, then that means `yellowButton` is probably a class field that you didn't notice.

Check the class again. What you probably have is something more like this:

```
class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{  
    private JButton yellowButton;

    public ButtonPanel()
    {  
        yellowButton = new JButton("Yellow");
        /* this.yellowButton == yellowButton */

        /* etc */
    }
}
```

If a variable `foo` cannot be found in a method scope, it automatically falls back to `this.foo`. In contrast, some languages like PHP do not have this flexibility. (For PHP you always have to do `$this->foo` instead of `$foo` to access class fields.)

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't work, You always need to declare the type of your variable. Are you sure you not missing a piece of code somewhere?

Like this at the beggining.

```
private JButton yellowButton = null;
```