# event handling question

Tags: java, event-handling

```
yellowButton.addActionListener(this);
```

what is (this) referring to in the addActionListener method. and can someone tell me how actionListener method works?

Comment: Interesting; we just had one of your classmates here a couple of hours ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310649/can-somebody-explain-how-this-works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is the current object. It has to implement the `ActionListener` interface.

This is often used in order to have all the related code in one place. But you can also use `yellowButton.addActionListener(new ButtonActionListener())`, where `ButtonActionListener` is another class of yours.

Classes that implement `ActionListener` should specify what happens when an action happens.

Comment: which object the JButton object. Is it referring to itself?

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the current object. The current object implements the interface [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html). When an action happens, the [actionPerformed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29) method is invoked.